# Redirecting to Controller not Passing Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, controller

I'm redirecting from one controller to another. The receiving controller, `uploads`, doesn't have an `index` action, but has a `create` action, which I'm trying to use obviously. However when I redirect, I get the following issue

***Unknown action**
The action 'index' could not be found for UploadsController*

`redirect_to :controller => 'uploads', :action => 'create', flash: {error: "there was an error"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because the redirect_to is assuming that its redirecting with a GET request.

Since the index & create actions both go to the same path and depending on the HTTP verb, Rails decides which action to call...

So if the application gets a GET request to /uploads it will render the index action and if it gets a POST it will call the create action.

Furthermore, I don't think you can redirect_to a http POST...  Are you sure that's what you want to do?

Comment: Yup, was a `GET/POST` issue. Realized that I don't want to even redirect to the POST action anyway, but still nice to know why it was happening!

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying `:method => :post` in the request. Create actions should only respond to that, unless you're doing fancy things with routes.